# Update html with js instead of creating new file

Tags: javascript, html

at this moment my script downloads html file with name(1), name(2) etc. I wonder if I can change this script to update  local file and add value instead of downloading. Or second option can I somehow force html to look for file "INCFINDERdb("highestvalue").html" ?

```js
function save() {
  var htmlContent = [document.getElementById('saveinc').value];
  var bl = new Blob(htmlContent, {
    type: "text/html"
  });
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(bl);
  a.download = "INCFINDERdb.html";
  a.hidden = true;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.innerHTML = " random ";
  a.click();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('click-me3').addEventListener('click', save);

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="saveinc">
<button class="button" id='click-me3'> Save INCs to ignore </button>

<div class="info-box">
  IGNORUJEMY TE CI
  <iframe src="/INCdb/INCFINDERdb.html" title="description"></iframe>

</div>
```

Later on I want to add remove option also with update does  `document.removeElement` will work?

Comment: JavaScript can't read files directly. It has to get the file from a file selector that the user chooses from.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: Please do some research before asking. I put "removeElement" in a search engine and the first result was a link to [`Element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove).

Comment: Also When the html file loads the js file attached to it is downloaded and then it runs

Comment: You can try the new File System Access API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function (item, suggest) {
    suggest({ filename: '..', conflictAction: 'overwrite' });
});
```

Fixed my problem